# read different data types in line c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm starting in c++ and I need to read a binary file.

I know the structure of file, i.e, each file line is composed by:

```
'double';'int8';'float32';'float32';'float32';'float32';'float32';'float32';'int8';'float32';'float32';'float32';'float32';'int8';'float32'
```

or in byte numbers:

```
8 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 4
```

I made some code but is too obsolete...
Here is the code:

```
void test1 () {
const char *filePath = "C:\20110527_phantom19.elm2";    
double *doub;           
int *in;
float *fl;
FILE *file = NULL;     
unsigned char buffer;

if ((file = fopen(filePath, "rb")) == NULL)
    cout << "Could not open specified file" << endl;
else
    cout << "File opened successfully" << endl;

// Get the size of the file in bytes
long fileSize = getFileSize(file);
cout << "Tamanho do ficheiro: " << fileSize;
cout << "\n";
// Allocate space in the buffer for the whole file
doub = new double[1];
in = new int[1];
fl = new float[1];
// Read the file in to the buffer
//fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file);

//fscanf(file, "%g %d %g", doub[0],in[0],fl[0]);

fread(doub, 8, 1, file);
//cout << doub[0]<< " ";
fseek (file ,8, SEEK_SET);
fread(&buffer,1,1,file);
//printf("%d ",buffer);
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(&buffer,1,1,file);
//printf("%d ",buffer);
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< " ";
fread(&buffer,1,1,file);
//printf("%d ",buffer);
fread(fl,4,1,file);
//cout << fl[0]<< "\n";

cin.get();
//delete[]fileBuf;
fclose(file); 
}
```

How can I change this to an efficient way?

Comment: You say it's a binary file. How are the lines separated?

Comment: In fact, there are no lines in the file. The file itself is constituted by the same sandard byte sequence, ie, 8 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 8 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 ...

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem when you can easily read whole structs with your custom format and have the fields automatically filled with correct values?

```
struct MyDataFormat {
  double d;
  int8 i1;
  float32 f[6];
  ..
};

MyDataFormat buffer;

fread(&buffer, sizeof(MyDataFormat), 1, file);
```

Comment: +1, he should probably use some "pack" directive, like `__attribute__((packed))`.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't work.  It might accidentally work for a given version of a given compiler, on a given platform, but it certainly doesn't work generally.

Comment: But, in this case, when you are using fread, you are reading only 1 element and this element, in this case, will have 55 bytes and the goal is reading 15 elements at the same time (55 bytes).

Comment: Just do a `for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)` and do 15 `fread`s, where's the problem?

Comment: @JamesKanze According to what you need to do this can effectively be your best solution. I used it SO MANY times in years of development :)

Comment: Now, I read the elements but the integer one, does not appear. I declared it like `unsigned char i1;`. What is wrong?

Comment: @Jack Except that it only works in very limited cases.  It's a guaranteed problem down the road in most cases.  (At it usually fails immediately on Intel's, because the binary format happens to be standard Internet format, which is different from the internal format of Intel.)

Answer (score 1):

If each line is the same format I would probably read a line at a time into a buffer and then have a function that pulled that buffer apart into separate elements - easier to understand, easier to test, works with larger files and is possibly more efficent to do fewer reads.

Comment: If the data has a binary format, as seems to be the case, `getline` isn't going to work.

Comment: @JamesKanze - reading a line doesn't mean getline(). Just that it's inefficient to read 1 byte then 4 bytes then ... but it's also bad to read an entire 4Gb file into memory that is then swapped out. Reading a block (ie line) at a time is in this case an easy solution. Best of all is mmap() but I didn't want to confuse things

Comment: Reading a fixed size block is good.  Reading a line is bad, when the concept of line doesn't exist.  (Of course, there's also nothing particularly inefficient about reading it byte by byte.  Both `FILE*` and `std::istream` will take care of any buffering issues.)

Comment: @JamesKanze - the OP referred to it as a `line` so it was simpler to say `line` rather than record/block/data unit when answering their question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "structure" of the file, we need to know the format
of the data types involved, and what you mean by "line", if the format
isn't a text format.  In general, however, you will 1) have to read an
appropriately sized block, and then extract each value from it,
according to the specified format.  For integral values, it's fairly
easy to extract an unsigned integral value using shifts; for `int8`, in
fact, you just have to read the byte.  For most machines, just casting
the unsigned integer into the correspondingly sized signed type will
work, although this is explicitly not guaranteed; if the `unsigned char`
is greater than `CHAR_MAX`, you'll have to scale it down to get the
appropriate value: something like `-(UCHAR_MAX+1 - value)` should do the
trick (for `char`s—for larger types, you also have to worry about
the fact that `UINT_MAX+1` will overflow).

*If* the external format is IEEE, and that's also what your machine
uses (the usual case for Windows and Unix machines, but rarely the case
for mainframes), then you can read an unsigned 4 or 8 byte integer
(again, using shifts), and type pun it, something like:

```
uint64_t
get64BitUInt( char const* buffer )
{
    return reinterpret_cast<double>(
          ((buffer[0] << 52) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[1] << 48) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[2] << 40) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[3] << 32) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[4] << 24) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[5] << 16) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[6] <<  8) & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[7]      ) & 0xFF) );
}

double
getDouble( char const* buffer )
{
    uint64_t retval = get64BitUInt( buffer );
    return *reinterpret_cast<double*>( &retval );
}
```

(This corresponds the usual network byte order.  If your binary format
uses another convention, you'll have to adapt it.  And the
`reinterpret_cast` depends on implementation defined behavior; you may
have to rewrite it as:

```
double
getDouble( char const* buffer )
{
    union
    {
        double          d;
        uint64_t        i;
    }               results;
    results.i = get64BitUInt( buffer );
    return results.d;
}
```

.  Or even use `memcpy` to copy from a `uint64_t` into a `double`.)

If your machine doesn't use IEEE floating point, and the external format
is IEEE, you'll have to pick up the 8 byte word as an 8 byte unsigned
int (`unsigned long long`), then extract the sign, exponent and mantissa
according to the IEEE format; something like the following:

```
double
getDouble( char const* buffer )
{
    uint64_t            tmp( get64BitUInt( buffer );
    double              f = 0.0 ;
    if ( (tmp & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) != 0 ) {
        f = ldexp( ((tmp & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF) | 0x0010000000000000),
                   (int)((tmp & 0x7FF0000000000000) >> 52) - 1022 - 53 ) ;
    }
    if ( (tmp & 0x8000000000000000) != 0 ) {
        f = -f ;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Don't do this until you're sure you'll need it, however.

Comment: In fact, there are no lines in the file. The file itself is constituted by the same sandard byte sequence, ie, 8 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 8 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 ...

Comment: @luiserta That's what I understood.  It sounded like a binary format, and binary formats don't contain "lines" (which in C++ are defined as sequences of printable characters terminated by a `'\n'`).  Do **not** use `getline` on this file; one of the bytes in a float or a double may look like a `'\n'`.  Use `std::istream::read` for the exact number of bytes in the block, then parse as above.  (And there's an error in my first version of `getDouble`, which I'll fix with an edit.)